# Is this proposition regarding conservative vector fields correct?

Tags: vector-analysis

I have a proposition here with a suggest for a proof. I did not find this in my textbook, which surprised me, since it seems so obvious and simple, and seems to me to give a very easy way to know for sure whether a particular vector field is conservative or not (at least if it is easily integratable). The fact that it is not in my textbook makes me think I made a mistake.

Here it is:

> ***Proposition.*** Let $F(x,y) = \binom{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ be a vector field. If $$\int f(x,y)dx = \int g(x,y)dy=\phi(x,y),$$ for some $\phi$, then $F$ is a conservative vector field with $F = \nabla \phi$.
>
> **proof**. Let $$\phi(x,y)= \int f(x,y)dx = \int g(x,y)dy$$  Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\delta\phi/\delta x=f(x,y)$, and
>   $\delta\phi/\delta y = g(x,y)$.
>
> Hence, $F=\nabla \phi$, which completes the proof.

If this proposition is correct, then all we need to do to check whether a vector field is conservative is to check the integral of both dimensions of the field and see whether they are the same.

Comment: So show me what you're going to do with $F(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} x+y \\ x+e^y \end{pmatrix}$. Note that the symbol $\int f(x,y)dx$ really hasn't been defined.

Comment: Check the third topic on http://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_determine , it might give you an insight.

Comment: What do you do about the constants of integration?